# org-drill doesn't load with spacemacs configuration

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-drill

I am trying to load [org-drill](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-drill.html) in Emacs with [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) configuration.

I have added the module into `.spacemacs` file as:

```el
(custom-set-variable
 ;; ...
 '(org-modules
   (quote
    (org-bbdb org-bibtex org-docview org-gnus org-info org-irc org-mhe org-rmail org-w3m org-drill)))
  ;; ...
)
```

Now when I am opening `spanish.org` (as in instruction), I see an error in `*Messages*` buffer:

> Problems while trying to load feature `org-drill`

*Does anyone know how can I fix this?*

Thanks

Comment: How about trying placing `(require 'org-drill)` in your `.emacs` file, and restarting Emacs?

Answer (score 3):

See this issue https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1218.

Basically `org-drill.el` is not included in the original emacs distribution, so one way you can include the file is to now add `org-plus-contrib` under `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`, which will download all `org-contrib` files, including `org-drill.el`

This would look as follows :

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(org-plus-contrib)
```

More info can be seen at :  https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#without-a-layer

Answer (score 0):

I would try with

```
(custom-set-variable
...
 '(org-modules
   (org-bbdb org-bibtex org-docview org-gnus org-info org-irc org-mhe org-rmail org-w3m org-drill))
...
)
```

The `quote` in the `'(org....)` sounds redundant.