# How to install org-drill on Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, org-drill

The following is my failed attempt at installing org-drill on Spacemacs.

I tried following instructions on https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill
But there is no "org-modules" in my .spacemacs file.
And there is no .emacs file on my Spacemacs install.

So I added "org-plus-contrib" to .spacemacs file as described in [org-drill doesn't load with spacemacs configuration](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12404/org-drill-doesnt-load-with-spacemacs-configuration/12424#12424)

I added "org-drill" to .spacemacs file, dotspacemacs-configuration-layers.

When I run dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers and reload the config file with <kbd>SPC f e R</kbd> I get the following message:

```
FAIL: org-drill
```

What is the proper way to install org-drill on .spacemacs?

**Update**

Thanks to Nick I successfully installed org-drill on my Spacemacs.
org-mode was already installed.
The org-drill install went something like this:

Press <kbd>C-h v</kbd>
Describe variable: org-modules
Press <kbd>RET</kbd>.
In help buffer, move point to "customize" link and <kbd>RET</kbd>.
Scroll down and check "External packages:"
Package: drill
Click "State" button and "Save for Future Sessions"
Run dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers <kbd>SPC f e R</kbd>
Done.
Check box "drill" is now in list, check it.
Scroll up and click "Apply and Save" button.
Run dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers <kbd>SPC f e R</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if when you entered in `customize` your action took some effect. Check if your `custom-set-variables` has some reference to org-modules variable.

Comment: <kbd>C-h v</kbd> Describe variable: custom-set-variables<br>
No variables are listed.

Comment: No, I mean, your `custom-set-variables` session at the end of your .spacemacs config file

Comment: For your knowledge, when you ask for `customize` a variable the config file is edited automatically which the choices you asked. In this case, if you customize the `org-modules` variable one entry in the section `custom-set-variables` is automatically created. So, if your variable is not defined anymore I guess some modification to this section of your config file could be changed.

Comment: My .spacemacs file does not have "org-modules".  The end of my .spacemacs file is appended to the question.

Comment: I reinstall spacemacs by deleting .spacemacs file and then restarting emacs.  That fixed it.

Comment: Nice to know! One Good thing to avoid issues like this is to keep your dotfiles under version control. There are a couple of ways to do this. I'm contributing to the github dotfile page where you find the most popular tools and insights to make this job as automated as possible. Take a look at the project page: dotfiles.github.io

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact your `org-modules` variable is not set in your `.spacemacs` file.

In order to see or change this variable you need to call:

<kbd>C-h v</kbd> , type `org-modules` and then press <kbd>RET</kbd>.

In the help menu that pops up you can see its value and also to `customize` it using the proper UI as explained in the Emacs manual [Easy Customize](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Changing-a-Variable.html#Changing-a-Variable), but if you are confortable with  manually editing your config file the procedure is very simple and described below:

First take note of the original value of the `org-modules` variable.

Now insert the whole variable in the `custom-set-variables` section that is the end of your `.spacemacs` file, adding `org-drill` at the end, like this:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-modules
   (quote
    (org-bbd org-bibtex ... org-drill)))
...
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandro.  I appended a "Update 1" to the question.

Comment: I still can't get this to work in spacemacs... I tried adding org-drill to the additional packages list, and tried going both the customize-variable route and the manual addition to .spacemacs - in the customize-variable screen I didn't get "drill" added to the list of checkboxes (other than the line of the external modules where I added it), and in the manual way I got a different value than what's shown here - all of the modules had ol- prefix instead of org- prefix... any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can set the variable `org-modules` in your Emacs init file. Below is my settings:

[image]

You can see the `org-drill` module listed in this variable. Also do not forget to add `(require 'org-drill)` in your init file. You can include whatever you want here to make it loaded in Emacs.